# В городе Москва или в городе Москве?

Tags: склонение, ономастика, топонимика

Как правильно сказать:
"в городе Москва" или "в городе Москве"?

Answer (score 10):

Правильно: *в городе Москв**е***. По правилам географические названия славянского происхождения согласуются с определяемым словом, то есть склоняются. Подробнее — здесь: [Как склонять географические названия?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

Comment: Вообще-то для разных типов топонимов - разные правила. 
Но для городов - да: название согласуется в падеже с родовым словом "город".