# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно сказать: "в городе Москва" или "в городе Москве"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В городе Москва или в городе Москве?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/%d0%92-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: altiba Надо заглядывать в Поиск по сайту. Это удобно, Вам понравится.

Comment: Так это один и тот же участник. Очень странно: вопрос задан через пять часов.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Интересный вопрос.  Если жить в городе Москве, или в городе Москва.   Вообще-то склоняется Москва. Если про это не знать, то есть сдать ЕГЭ, не изучая языка, то можно и не склонять.

Answer (score 4):

В г. Москве, разумеется. В связи с чем название города вдруг перестало склоняться?

Answer (score 1):

А при чем тут ЕГЭ и "не изучение языка"? Склонять всегда нужно.