# Уточнение или часть предложения

Tags: запятые, уточнения

Нужна ли запятая в предложении:

***Убедитесь, что в разделе меню выбрали город Москва (,) в левом верхнем углу.***

Как легко определить, являются ли "указатели" уточнением, чтобы правильно выделить их?
Понимаю, что само предложение лучше переформулировать, но здесь есть необходимость работать с готовым тестом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это присоединение. То есть когда есть некое предложение с завершённым смыслом, а к нему после паузы добавляется прибавочное сочетание. Вот пара примеров из справочника Розенталя:

> Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, во фраке (Герц.).
> Он умер, в Томске (М. Г.).
> Ночью я стою у орудия, дневальным (Кат.).

Запятая ставится.

Comment: Спасибо! Так стало понятнее :)

Answer (score 1):

О конструкции "город Москва". Здесь есть два варианта написания:
*выбрали город Москву* (в сочетании со словом "город" названия склоняются);
*выбрали "город Москва"* (название раздела заключается в кавычки, не склоняется).

*Убедитесь, что в разделе меню выбрали город Москву в левом верхнем углу.*
И при запятой, и при ее отсутствии возникает ощущение, что в меню существует еще один раздел "город Москва", находящийся в другом углу (правом нижнем, например).

*Убедитесь, что в разделе меню выбрали город Москву (левый верхний угол).*
*Убедитесь, что в разделе меню выбрали "город Москва" (левый верхний угол).*
Я бы оформила предложение с помощью скобок — в этом случае информация однозначна.
[Вставка](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/vstavnye-konstruktsii.html) не является членом предложения.

[В городе Москва или в городе Москве?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/%D0%92-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5)